# How to check Content hub version?

Tags: content-hub

Is there any way to check the version of `Sitecore Content Hub`?

It should be somewhere inside manage page but i couldn't find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use url - `https://sitecorecontenthubURL/api/status`

It will show a json format, search for **product_version**, it will tell you the Content Hub version.

[image]