# How to check Sitecore Content Hub Version

Tags: content-hub

When I browse https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.com/api/status as mentioned [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35053/how-to-check-content-hub-version), there is a Guid value for the product version property

```
{
  "product_version": "7d2ea05460a1e362117f54876100f2c7b3025314",
  "build_date": "2023-08-11T12:59:44+00:00",
  "hostname": "abcd-p-001-portal-ui-6cfb8fcdf6-2q74n",
  "region_name": null,
  "aggregated_service_status_label": "Red",
  "index_template_versions": {
    "main_template_version": "15000",
    "audit_template_version": {
      "default_template": "15000"
    }
  },
  "queues": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/queues",
    "title": "Status of the message queues"
  },
  "jobs": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/jobs",
    "title": "Status of the processing jobs"
  },
  "users": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/users",
    "title": "Status of the user base"
  },
  "license": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/license",
    "title": "State of your license"
  },
  "system": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/system",
    "title": "Obsolete resource, use the graph, data storage and or search resource instead"
  },
  "data_storage": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/datastorage",
    "title": "Status and statistics of the data storage layer"
  },
  "media_storage": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/mediastorage",
    "title": "Status and statistics of the media storage layer"
  },
  "search": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/search",
    "title": "Status and statistics of the search services"
  },
  "graph": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/graph{?forceRefresh}",
    "title": "Status and statistics of the graph server and its workers",
    "templated": true
  },
  "service_status": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/servicestatus",
    "title": "Detailed service status explaining the aggregated status"
  },
  "publishing": {
    "href": "https://mysite.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/status/publishing",
    "title": "State of publishing functionality"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

According to this [article](https://timmarsh.co.uk/2023/08/02/sitecore-content-hub-getting-the-version-of-your-environment/#:%7E:text=of%20Content%20Hub.-,You%20need%20to%20log%20in%20to%20your%20Content%20Hub%20instance,and%20what%20that%20version%20contains), for 4.2+ there is no version and just the dates.

If the new version is the date, then how do we check for the latest documentation as the docs are currently categorized by versions.

Answer (score 2):

With `4.2+` version previous version has now been removed/disabled (Check July 17, 2023 Improvements [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/whats-new--whats-new-in-content-hub.html)), however, the version number is now shown within the user interface of Content Hub.

You need to log in to your Content Hub instance and click on the `Manage` button in the top right. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and the version is shown here.

[image]

If you go to the new [Content Hub – Whats new page](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/whats-new--whats-new-in-content-hub.html) you can easily find out what release you are on and what that version contains.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The bottom right shows only the date. For me it is `11 Aug 2023`. How should I map it to a version  like 4.1, 4.2 etc. Also, in the "What's new" page, there are a list of versions and the latest is `4.1.0 Nov 1, 2021`. But there is also an "Add Version" button, which means I can add my own. Should the admins keep updating. If not how do I confirm what is the right version.

Answer (score 2):

@SumitHelaiya mentioned is the new way to know the version, now instead of version it was showing previously it is showing updated dates in right bottom panel of manage page. Please refer this url - [https://timmarsh.co.uk/2023/08/02/sitecore-content-hub-getting-the-version-of-your-environment/#:~:text=of%20Content%20Hub.-,You%20need%20to%20log%20in%20to%20your%20Content%20Hub%20instance,and%20what%20that%20version%20contains](https://timmarsh.co.uk/2023/08/02/sitecore-content-hub-getting-the-version-of-your-environment/#:%7E:text=of%20Content%20Hub.-,You%20need%20to%20log%20in%20to%20your%20Content%20Hub%20instance,and%20what%20that%20version%20contains).

I found 1 more url - https://content-hub-url/api/status/system, if you hit this url it showing some more information that might be helpful to you.

[image]

Comment: This URL `https://content-hub-url/api/status/system` does give additional info but still doesn't specify the version. If the new version is the date, then how do you check for the latest documentation of the respective version, because currently they are categorized by versions

Answer (score 2):

Kindly refer to the **Content Hub Versioning Policy** document. As per the document, the releases dates will progressively replace semantic versioning to identify different versions of Content Hub.

Each version is associated with a specific release date. The release date allows customers to keep track of when new features and improvements have been introduced.

Customers can use this information to identify when specific functionality was added to the product using the release notes or other available documentation and determine if they need to update their processes or workflows to take advantage of these features.

Refer to this article for more details.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002994

Also, you can search for more specific information about the content hub using this URL.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_search&spa=1&u_affected_software=sitecore_content_hub&language=en

Hope this helps.